# How to recover missing Grub File

Tags: rhel, grub2

On my test system. I was doing some testing and i move the *grub.conf* file from **/boot/grub/** to **/opt/**

And on boot black screen came as expected with just **grub>** written on it. I tried to solve it using some tuts but it is not working.

/boot is on /dev/sda1

is there a way to recover grub.conf without using live media.

**Sorry i forgot to add that this server is installed uisng Linux KVM Technology**

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to to ad the `grub>` prompt, is to run this command:

```
root
(hd0,0): Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83
```

this will tell you what is your `/boot` partition and the filesystem type; in your specific case, it seems that you should have the /boot (the root of grub) under the `(hd0,0)`.

Next one, you have to do:

```
kernel (hd0,0)/vmlinuz-2.6.32-xxx.el.xxx root=/dev/sda1
```

this will tell grub that we want to use the `vmlinuz-xxxxxxx` kernel that is located in `/boot`. The root argument should be modified according your disk configuration. In case of LVM, please look at the example I'm providing you later in this answer to modify it.

Now, run this:

```
initrd (hd0,0)/initramfs-2.6.32-xxx.el.xxx
```

this will tell grub to use this specific initramfs to boot the machine.

And finally:

```
boot
```

this should boot nicely your machine.

Please note that you can use the TAB completion when entering all the filenames and commands here provided.

---

LVM kernel + root argument example

```
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-xxx ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_server-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_server/lv_root rd_NO_DM
```

Answer (score 0):

Boot the system from an installation boot medium.

Type `linux rescue` at the installation boot prompt to enter the rescue environment.

Type `chroot /mnt/sysimage` to mount the root partition.

Type `/sbin/grub-install bootpart` to reinstall the GRUB boot loader, where `bootpart` is the boot partition (typically, /dev/sda).

Review the `/boot/grub/grub.conf` file, as additional entries may be needed for GRUB to control additional operating systems.
    Reboot the system.

Comment: This server was installed using KVM tech. I performed this step but on boot it says BOOTING FROM HARD DISK and hang there